# JavaScript Multiple Error Messages

Tags: javascript, validation, dom

The user enters input, clicks a button, and a function is called to perform some calculations.  If a field is not of the correct type or value, then an error message is displayed.  If one of the fields is wrong, then that field needs to have an error message displayed.  If multiple fields are wrong, then those fields need to have an error message displayed.  Right now the page is only displaying one of the error messages if a field is wrong, even if all the fields are wrong.  I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I keep banging my head against the wall.  Any suggestions?  Thank you!  Here is the applicable portion of code:

```
    if (isNaN(theMilesDriven) || theMilesDriven <= 0) {
            theMilesDrivenError.firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a number greater than 0 for the miles driven.";
            return false;
        }

        if (isNaN(theGallonsUsed) || theGallonsUsed <= 0) {
            theGallonsUsedError.firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a number greater than 0 for the gallons of gas used.";
            return false;
        }

        if (isNaN(thePriceGallon) || thePriceGallon <= 0) {
            thePriceGallonError.firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a number greater than 0 for the price per gallon.";
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: A `return` statement exits the function immediately.

Comment: remove `return` statement

Comment: So, if I remove the return statements altogether and put the calculation within an else statement, does that seem like a valid fix?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution will still make the calculation if one of the first two errors is found. Here is an alternative:

```
    var isErrorFound = false;

    if (isNaN(theMilesDriven) || theMilesDriven <= 0) {
        theMilesDrivenError.firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a number greater than 0 for the miles driven.";
        isErrorFound = true;
    }

    if (isNaN(theGallonsUsed) || theGallonsUsed <= 0) {
        theGallonsUsedError.firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a number greater than 0 for the gallons of gas used.";
        isErrorFound = true;
    }

    if (isNaN(thePriceGallon) || thePriceGallon <= 0) {
        thePriceGallonError.firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a number greater than 0 for the price per gallon.";
        isErrorFound = true;
    }

    if (!isErrorFound) {
        //Perform the calculations and write the results to the page
        var milesPerGallon = theMilesDriven / theGallonsUsed;
        var theMPG = document.getElementById("mpg");
        theMPG.firstChild.nodeValue = "Your MPG is: " + milesPerGallon.toFixed(2);

        var cost = theGallonsUsed * thePriceGallon;
        var theCost = document.getElementById("cost");
        theCost.firstChild.nodeValue = "Your cost for this trip is: $" + cost.toFixed(2);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think I've got it now.  I made your suggested changes as well as a few others.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did that seemed to solve the problem:

```
    //Verify the input is numerical and greater than 0
        if (isNaN(theMilesDriven) || theMilesDriven <= 0) {
            theMilesDrivenError.firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a number greater than 0 for the miles driven.";
        }

        if (isNaN(theGallonsUsed) || theGallonsUsed <= 0) {
            theGallonsUsedError.firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a number greater than 0 for the gallons of gas used.";
        }

        if (isNaN(thePriceGallon) || thePriceGallon <= 0) {
            thePriceGallonError.firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a number greater than 0 for the price per gallon.";
        }

        else {
            //Perform the calculations and write the results to the page
            var milesPerGallon = theMilesDriven / theGallonsUsed;
            var theMPG = document.getElementById("mpg");
            theMPG.firstChild.nodeValue = "Your MPG is: " + milesPerGallon.toFixed(2);

            var cost = theGallonsUsed * thePriceGallon;
            var theCost = document.getElementById("cost");
            theCost.firstChild.nodeValue = "Your cost for this trip is: $" + cost.toFixed(2);
        }
```

Comment: This was done thanks to the suggestions of others, which are much appreciated.